# PHP/MYSQL Making a shopping cart coupon code work for one of two products

Tags: php, sql, shopping-cart

Ok this has me stumped..

I currently have a system where a shopping cart checks a coupon table to see if the coupon code the shopper enters is valid for the product.

This works fine, but I'm looking to expand the system so a single code can be used for one of a number of products.

**Here's the working code as it stands:**

```
$coupon = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strtoupper($_POST['coupon'])));
$coup_qry = mysql_query("select tblcoupon.*, sell_product.product_code,sell_product.id from tblcoupon,sell_product WHERE tblcoupon.code='$coupon' AND sell_product.product_code = tblcoupon.products");
if($numrows = mysql_num_rows($coup_qry) > 0) // check if typed coupon exists in tblcoupon table 
{
    while($coup_w = mysql_fetch_array($coup_qry))           
    {
        $start_date = $coup_w['start_date'];
        $end_date = $coup_w['end_date'];
        $start = strtotime($start_date);
        $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $today = strtotime($todays_date);
        $expiration_date = strtotime($end_date);
        if($today >= $start && $today <= $expiration_date) // if todays date is > start date 
                                                            and < end date then execute the below script                
        {   
            $coupon_productcode = $coup_w['products'];    //product code in the tblcoupon table
            $sell_product_productcode = $coup_w['product_code'];
            //check if any of the products in the shopping cart match any of the products 
            foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $name => $value) 
            {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                if($id==$coup_w['id'])
                {
                    $_SESSION['coupon'] = "C$coupon-$id";
                    if(isset($_SESSION['offer'])) { 
                        unset($_SESSION['offer']); 
                    }
                    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) { 
                        unset($_SESSION['error']); 
                    }       
                    $errCoupon = "Coupon code accepted-green";
                } 
                else {
                    $errCoupon = "Coupon Code is Invalid for this product.";
                }
            }
        } 
        else if ($today < $start){
            $errCoupon = "Coupon Code is not yet active!-red";
        } 
        else if ($today > $expiration_date){
            $errCoupon = "Coupon Code has expired!-red";
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to add a new column in `tbl_coupon` called `products2` (this would be a different product code), and have the SQL query look for rows where `sell_product.product_code = tblcoupon.products OR sell_product.product_code = tblcoupon.products2`

Then, I need to check the `$_SESSION['cart']` `$id` for the product being either valid option (`products` or `products2`), but not both. The coupons can only work for one of the 2 options.

Any help would be wonderful.

If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want to make coupons that work for multiple products but can only be applied to one item. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$coupon = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strtoupper($_POST['coupon'])));
$coup_qry = mysql_query("select tblcoupon.*, sell_product.product_code,sell_product.id from tblcoupon,sell_product WHERE tblcoupon.code='$coupon' AND sell_product.product_code = tblcoupon.products");
if($numrows = mysql_num_rows($coup_qry) > 0) // check if typed coupon exists in tblcoupon table 
    {
        while($coup_w = mysql_fetch_array($coup_qry))           
                    {
                        $coup_w['used'] = 0; //Coupon has not been used yet
                        $start_date = $coup_w['start_date'];
                        $end_date = $coup_w['end_date'];
                        $start = strtotime($start_date);
                        $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
                        $today = strtotime($todays_date);
                        $expiration_date = strtotime($end_date);
                        if($today >= $start && $today <= $expiration_date) // if todays date is > start date and < end date then execute the below script               
                            {   
                                $coupon_productcode = $coup_w['products'];  //product code in the tblcoupon table
                                $sell_product_productcode = $coup_w['product_code'];
                                //check if any of the products in the shopping cart match any of the products 
                                foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $name => $value) 
                                    {
                                        $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                                        //test if the coupon matches AND has not been used
                                        if($id == $coup_w['id'] && $coup_w['used'] == 0)                                                
                                            {                                                                                                       
                                                $_SESSION['coupon'] = "C$coupon-$id";
                                                if(isset($_SESSION['offer'])) { unset($_SESSION['offer']); }                                                    
                                                if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) { unset($_SESSION['error']); }                                                    
                                                $errCoupon = "Coupon code accepted-green";
                                                $coup_w['used'] = 1; //Coupon has now been used.
                                            } 
                                        else {$errCoupon = "Coupon Code is Invalid for this product.";}                                         
                                    }
                            } 
                        else if ($today < $start){$errCoupon = "Coupon Code is not yet active!-red";} 
                        else if ($today > $expiration_date){$errCoupon = "Coupon Code has expired!-red";}
                    }
```

}

A simple solution to the "only use a coupon once" portion would be to carry a 'used' key in the $coup_w array that would indicate if the coupon has been used (0 if false, 1 if true). Then you need to test if the coupon id matches AND the coupon has not been used. If the conditions are met, the coupon is valid and 'used' should be set to 1.

As for the 'product1/product2' I dont think you should limit yourself by a number of columns. I think the best way to do it would be to do something like:

```
//YOU'LL HAVE TO MAKE SURE THIS IS VALID, I'M NOT SURE, BUT THE LOGIC IS THE IDEA
"SELECT ... AND tblcoupon.products LIKE CONCAT('%', sell_product.product_code, '%')"
```

where tblcoupon.products is a comma delimited list of the product codes that the coupon would be valid for.

I should also mention that it is inadvisable to use the mysql_ functions. You should look into mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: shall try that today and see if it behaves, thanks. Sadly I'm suck using mysql for the sake of conformity, I didn't write the E-commerce site I'm attempting to patch flaws with the code that was written by the previous web-developer.. (I am thankfully working on a full rewrite too, but that's going to take much longer, while my delightful sales team need the coupon changes by next week :p )

Comment: Just tested with the CONCAT, the carts throwing a few undefined errors, but the concept works.. I've a code that works for one of three products currently (errors aside) and if you try to apply it to all 3 items at once it only discounts the first on the list :) Thanks :) now to see if I can smooth it out.